# Returning circle with biggest area from a cluster

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7, python-requests

A list is given in form of (x,y,r) where x and y are center coordinates and r is radius.
For each cluster, the circle with the largest area is kept, and all other circles in that cluster are removed. Return the resulting tuple.

Code

```
import math

class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        super(Circle, self).__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r

    def get_distance(self, circle):
        return math.sqrt(math.pow(self.x - circle.x, 2) + math.pow(self.y - circle.y, 2))

    def is_intersect(self, circle):
        return self.get_distance(circle) < self.r + circle.r

    @staticmethod
    def has_intersections(list_circles):
        list_circles.sort(key=lambda a: a.x - a.r)
        sweep_intersected = []
        for circle in list_circles:
            for in_sweep in sweep_intersected:
                if circle.is_intersect(in_sweep):
                    return True
                if in_sweep.x + in_sweep.r < circle.x - circle.r:
                    sweep_intersected.remove(in_sweep)
            sweep_intersected.append(circle)
        return False

cir = [(12,5,0.9),(2,4,0.8),(2,3,0.4)]
cv1 = cir[0]
cv2 = cir[1]
cv3 = cir[2]
#cv4 = cir[3]
c1 = Circle(cv1[0], cv1[1], cv1[2])
c2 = Circle(cv2[0], cv2[1], cv2[2])
c3 = Circle(cv3[0], cv3[1], cv3[2])

a = []
cval = Circle.has_intersections([c1, c2, c3])
if cval == False:
  for num in range(len(cir)):
    break
  print(cir)
if cval == True:
  for n in range(len(cir)):
    #max(cir[n][2])
    a.append(cir[n][2])
    max_value = max(a)
    max_index = a.index(max_value)
  print(cir[max_index])
```

I have 2 main questions
1. How can I accept as a list of tuples from user and return list?
2. I am not able to pass below testcase. Thanks

Testcase
input: [(0.5,0.5,0.4), (1.7,1.3,1), (0.4,0.6,0.3)]
output: [(1.7,1.3,1)]

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: People seem to think of stackoverflow as a resource to solve their specific problem, rather than a community-built knowledge base.

Answer (score 1):

Making a naive aproach, for each circle tuple, you can calculate the distance from it to all other circles tuples, them calculate if this distance is greater than the sum of their radius. This way you will know if some circle is overlapping another, then the sum of radius will be smaller than their center's distance.

So you can define some function:

```
import math
def distance(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p2[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p2[1] - p1[1])**2)
```

and them defines a function for the overlap:

```
def isoverlapping(circle1, circle2):
    sum_of_radius = circle1[2] + circle2[2]
    distance_bettwen_circles = distance(circle1, circle2)
    return sum_of_radius >= distance_bettwen_circles
```

So, if the function above returns true, you will have to ignore the smaller circle. To do this you can make a function that calculates the area of circles and returns the greater:

```
def greatercircle(circle1, circle2):
    area1 = math.pi * circle1[2]
    area2 = math.pi * circle2[2]
    return circle1 if area1 >= area2 else circle2
```

now it's only needed to joint his in a loop:

```
output = []

# 1: Iterate over circles array, comparing every position with the others.
for index, circle in enumerate(circles):
#     2: get the other circles in array
    another_circles = circles[:index] + circles[index+1:]
    for another_circle in another_circles:
#         3: Iterate over the other circles
        if isoverlapping(circle, another_circle):
#         if an overlap ocurrs then get the greater circle.
#         Now this will be the current circle for comparison.
            greater = greatercircle(circle, another_circle)
            circle = greater
#   4: If this circle is already in output, do not append it.
    if circle not in output:
        output.append(circle)

print(output)
```

Hope that it can help you!

Comment: I didnt understand the last part, with above circles value I am getting different output. Can you explain? Thanks a lot

Comment: I am getting area for 1 two tuples i.e. (0.5,0.5,0.5), (1.5,1.5,1.1). With some other random tc I am getting area of two highest radius

Comment: Sorry, I an writting in cellphone, and cannot test with python terminal. But i just found that in greatercircle function I was returning the area instead of the circle. I will make some tests about the last scrap of code and check if everything will be ok!

Comment: Everything ok! I made corrections and put comments. Hope this works for you.

Comment: @EduardoMelo, to find the greater of two circles, you just need to compare their radii. You don't need to compute their areas.

Comment: @fountainhead I had not even noticed, it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only interested in keeping the circles with the largest, we can apply a greedy algorithm. Here we first sort all circles on the largest radius and than loop over them only adding them to our resulting set if they don't make any intersections if the circles we already included in our resulting set.

```
circles = [c1, c2, c3, c4]

from operator import attrgetter


def largest_non_overlapping_circles(circles):
    circles.sort(key=attrgetter('r'), reverse=True)  # sort on largest radius
    res = []  # list of circles we want to keep
    for c in circles:
        if not Circle.has_intersections(res + [c]):
            res.append(c)
    return res


print([(c.x, c.y, c.r) for c in largest_non_overlapping_circles(circles)])
```

For your second question we can make use of Python's `input()` function. Here I choose to ask for all numbers in one line (x, y, r). I also used a while loop so that the user can input more circles if he/she desires. There is no error handling, the application will just crash if there is unexpected input. Up to you to make this more fancier.

```
print("""Give each circle with three numbers using the decimal as a dot.
The three numbers should be resp. x y r and should be seperated by a space.""")
c1 = Circle(*map(float, input("Give first circle >> ").split()))
circles = [c1]
while "y" in input("Do you want to give another circle? >> "):
    circles.append(Circle(*map(float, input("Give another circle >> ").split())))

print([(c.x, c.y, c.r) for c in largest_non_overlapping_circles(circles)])
```